Using a data frame as a lookup table for creating dummies from the column names of another df
I have a dataframe "alldata" in which cases are organisations, with dummy variables in columns with names like Algeria_1954 - country_year. A "1" on that dummy variable means that the organisation is present in a given country in that year, for example in Algieria in 1954. I want to treat another df, "colonies_df", as a lookup table to create dummies. It has a column "country" with the name of country (for example "Algieria"), and columns for presence of a country in a colonial empire in a given year, for example col..france.1954 - col..empire.year. I want to create new dummies in alldata looking like colpresence..[empire].[year], based on the alldata case (organisation) scoring one on a dummy with country_year, and that country scoring one on col..empire.year for the specific empire and year. I've been trying to write a function for that in R, also with help of Chat GPT, but with no success. I would really appreciate help
These are the variables in colonies_df, with all the empires and years I want to use for my dummy variables:
> head(colonies_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 41
  country col..belgium.19~ col..belgium.19~ col..belgium.19~ col..belgium.20~
  <chr>              <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Afghan~                0                0                0                0
2 Albania                0                0                0                0
3 Algeria                0                0                0                0
4 Andorra                0                0                0                0
5 Angola                 0                0                0                0
6 Antigu~                0                0                0                0
# ... with 36 more variables: col..belgium.2017 <dbl>, col..britain.1954 <dbl>,
#   col..britain.1970 <dbl>, col..britain.1988 <dbl>, col..britain.2003 <dbl>,
#   col..britain.2017 <dbl>, col..france.1954 <dbl>, col..france.1970 <dbl>,
#   col..france.1988 <dbl>, col..france.2003 <dbl>, col..france.2017 <dbl>,
#   col..germany.1954 <dbl>, col..germany.1970 <dbl>, col..germany.1988 <dbl>,
#   col..germany.2003 <dbl>, col..germany.2017 <dbl>, col..italy.1954 <dbl>,
#   col..italy.1970 <dbl>, col..italy.1988 <dbl>, col..italy.2003 <dbl>,
#   col..italy.2017 <dbl>, col..netherlands.1954 <dbl>, col..netherlands.1970 <dbl>,
#   col..netherlands.1988 <dbl>, col..netherlands.2003 <dbl>,
#   col..netherlands.2017 <dbl>, col..portugal.1954 <dbl>, col..portugal.1970 <dbl>,
#   col..portugal.1988 <dbl>, col..portugal.2003 <dbl>, col..portugal.2017 <dbl>,
#   col..spain.1954 <dbl>, col..spain.1970 <dbl>, col..spain.1988 <dbl>,
#   col..spain.2003 <dbl>, col..spain.2017 <dbl>

I tried code like this:

# Define a function to create new dummy columns for presence of colonies in an empire for a specific year
create_col_presence <- function(row, colonies_df, empire, year) {
  # Check if the country has presence in the specific year in the empire
  country <- row$country
  if (row[[paste0(country, "_", year)]] == 1 && colonies_df[[paste0("col.", empire, ".", year)]] == 1) {
    return(1)  # Set presence to 1 if conditions are met
  } else {
    return(0)  # Set presence to 0 otherwise
  }
}

# Iterate over each row in alldata and generate new dummy columns for each empire and year
for (empire in c("belgium", "britain", "france", "germany", "italy", "netherlands", "portugal", "spain")) {
  for (year in c(1954, 1970, 1988, 2003, 2017)) {
    # Define the name of the new dummy column
    new_col_name <- paste0("colpresence_", empire, "_", year)
    
    # Create the new dummy column using the defined function
    alldata[[new_col_name]] <- sapply(1:nrow(alldata), function(i) create_col_presence(alldata[i, ], colonies_df, empire, year))
  }
}


Got this error:
> # Define a function to create new dummy columns for presence of colonies in an empire for a specific year
> create_col_presence <- function(row, colonies_df, empire, year) {
+   # Check if the country has presence in the specific year in the empire
+   country <- row$country
+   if (row[[paste0(country, "_", year)]] == 1 && colonies_df[[paste0("col.", empire, ".", year)]] == 1) {
+     return(1)  # Set presence to 1 if conditions are met
+   } else {
+     return(0)  # Set presence to 0 otherwise
+   }
+ }
> 
> # Iterate over each row in alldata and generate new dummy columns for each empire and year
> for (empire in c("belgium", "britain", "france", "germany", "italy", "netherlands", "portugal", "spain")) {
+   for (year in c(1954, 1970, 1988, 2003, 2017)) {
+     # Define the name of the new dummy column
+     new_col_name <- paste0("colpresence_", empire, "_", year)
+     
+     # Create the new dummy column using the defined function
+     alldata[[new_col_name]] <- sapply(1:nrow(alldata), function(i) create_col_presence(alldata[i, ], colonies_df, empire, year))
+   }
+ }
Error in if (row[[paste0(country, "_", year)]] == 1 && colonies_df[[paste0("col.",  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed


Welcome to SO. You'll get better and faster help if your question provides sample/toy data (a good way: dput(head(df)), the problematic code and desired output. Take a moment, read the link and update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example

I don't have access to an R install at the moment, have you tried putting a print function into your create_col_presence function?
 create_col_presence <- function(row, colonies_df, empire, year) {
   # Check if the country has presence in the specific year in the empire
   country <- row$country
   print(country)
   print(paste0(country, "_", year))
   print(paste0("col.", empire, ".", year))
   print(row[[paste0(country, "_", year)]])
   print(colonies_df[[paste0("col.", empire, ".", year)]])
   if (row[[paste0(country, "_", year)]] == 1 && colonies_df[[paste0("col.", empire, ".", year)]] == 1) {
     return(1)  # Set presence to 1 if conditions are met
   } else {
     return(0)  # Set presence to 0 otherwise
   }
 }

I think you'll find one of those will not look like you expect.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
